# Dropdown options copying into other scene's dropdown - Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, dropdown, prefab

I am working on dynamically generating dropdown list options through the script, and based on the option value and with some conditions other scenes should load. (by clicking on the dropdown value new scene should load). I have attached the all required scripts to a dropdown game object in all the scenes and the dynamic  dropdown options are working for starting scene but when a new scene is loaded the dropdown of new is empty, the values of the previous sense dropdown are not loading. Below is the script. Can anyone please give me a hint or a sample script to transfer the dropdown values from one scene to another. Thanks

''''

public class SceneLoad : MonoBehaviour
{

```
Dropdown m_Dropdown;
private ParseHandler parsehand;
int Scene_num;

public void AddDropdown()
{

    m_Dropdown = GetComponent<Dropdown>();
    m_Dropdown.ClearOptions();
    m_Dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData("--Starting Page--"));
    parsehand = GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(ParseHandler)) as ParseHandler;
    foreach (string threat in parsehand.GetList())
    {

        if (threat == "TMP")
        {
            m_Dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData("Vehicle on highway changing the lane"));

        }
        if (threat == "DOS")
        {
            m_Dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData("Vehicle on highway met with an accident"));
        }
        if (threat == "HJK")
        {
            m_Dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData("Pedestrians behind the vehicle While unparking"));

        }
       

    }

    m_Dropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { callingthescenes(m_Dropdown); });


}
private void callingthescenes(Dropdown mydropdown)
{
    select_scene(mydropdown.options[mydropdown.value].text);

}


public void select_scene(string scenetext)
{


    if (scenetext == "Pedestrians behind the vehicle While unparking")
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);

        Scene_num = 1;
    
    }
    if (scenetext == "Vehicle on highway changing the lane")
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);

        Scene_num = 2;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html). **DontDestoryOnLoad** method is a monobehaviour method that ensures when switching scene, object holds all references if exist in new scene, and values.

> The load of a new Scene destroys all current Scene objects. Call
> Object.DontDestroyOnLoad to preserve an Object during level loading.
> If the target Object is a component or GameObject, Unity also
> preserves all of the Transform’s children. Object.DontDestroyOnLoad
> does not return a value.

Usage, add this to your monobehaviour script, inside class.

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have added the "DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);" method, the result is the dynamic dropdown options are not generating only the default dropdown options are there. I even tried adding the DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); in awake method, Now the dynamic dropdpwn options are populating in the first scene but in other scene only the default dropdown options are visible.                    To clarify my work: I have created 2 scenes and both scenes have the same gameobject and the gameobject has the same scripts attached in both the scenes

Comment: Try to add **[SerializableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=net-5.0)** to your class. Because, it seems like, your dynamically generated values added to variable in **Dropdown** class. So, if you mark it as serialized, Unity can store data. PS: I am not sure but you can try.